# There a big blank space when hiding DIV on a form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide a DIV in a form by using:          `document.getElementById('cost_pass').style.visibility = 'hidden';`

But when I do, the form keeps a blank space where the DIV used to be, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

This is not an error, visibility works that way (hiding the element, but preserving the space for it). Just try

```
document.getElementById('cost_pass').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: This is correct "visibility" maintains space. "display" hides it completely.

Comment: Great answer. William..May I suggest to checked Stormherz answer so he can get credited?

Answer (score 0):

Setting visibility to hidden just hides the DIV from the page, but the space it occupies is still there (visibility doesn't affect page flow).  You should look into using the Display property to hide/show your div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display